# Cant Find Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, community

I am new at a company and they are using a Js. code in one of their custom components. There is a button it calls upon an action. this action then creates an object called "Action" this action is then using the following code:

```
var Action = component.get("c.CreateEroll");
```

the problem I am having is that I have no idea what CreateEroll is it's not one of the components in the .cmp file. Is this part of Aura's components? How can I find this? I need to know what is inside that component to see what values it holds and what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateEroll` is presumably the name of a method in the Apex controller for this component.

If you're new to writing Aura, consider completing modules like [Aura Component Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics) on Trailhead, which will help you acclimate to the idioms of Aura, including the use of [server-side controllers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/lex_dev_lc_basics_server).

Comment: Yup looks like there is a class that has same method!